# undefined method `admin?' with Cancan

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, cancan

I have a problem finding out how to check for admin rights in CanCanCan.

With

- `if user.admin?` I get undefined method
- `if user.is?` I get undefined method
- `if user.has_attribute?(:admin)`
- `if user.user_type == "admin"` I get undefined method

I had some hopes with has_attribute, but it does not help, even if I get no alert. A `puts 'hey'` proves it in the console.

I started learning Rails a month ago and I experienced some limitations due to windows. Is it possible that my problem occurs because of windows?

> On the other hand, `if user.present?` works and it gives some hopes again.

My user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy

end
```

And the DB fields

```
  create_table "active_admin_comments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "namespace"
    t.text "body"
    t.string "resource_type"
    t.integer "resource_id"
    t.string "author_type"
    t.integer "author_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["author_type", "author_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_author_type_and_author_id"
    t.index ["namespace"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_namespace"
    t.index ["resource_type", "resource_id"], name: "index_active_admin_comments_on_resource_type_and_resource_id"
  end

  create_table "admin_users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_admin_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_admin_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

  create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "title"
    t.text "body"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "image_file_name"
    t.string "image_content_type"
    t.integer "image_file_size"
    t.datetime "image_updated_at"
    t.integer "author_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer "sign_in_count", default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end
```

From application_controller.rb

```
def access_denied(exception)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { head :forbidden, content_type: 'text/html' }
      format.html { redirect_to main_app.root_url, notice: exception.message }
   end
end
```

EDIT

> I thought for a while that the code suggested by @mrzasa would bring a solution as I had no more alert. This was because of my ability.rb :

```
if user.present?
  if user.admin?
    puts 'hey admin'
    can :manage, :all
  end
  can :read, all
  can :manage, Post, :author_id => user.id
    puts 'hey user'
end
```

> If I comment `# if user.present?` the alert `undefined method 'admin?'`comes back again. A proof that user.present works, but here to say that there is no user, until I log in outside of the admin panel as a user and then I can see the puts in the console. But I can't perform any action, unless I state `can :manage, :all` to ANY user.

At this stage, I've added `user ||= User.new` to create an instance of user before checking for an admin. Even if I allow any visitor to log in as an admin, user.admin? is never verified, unless I set `def admin?` to true in user.rb

I see that many people using Cancancan define roles instead. Maybe I should go for it...

EDIT 2

> It works! I worked on it again from the install of Cancancan to the point where I was with the additions of @mrzasa. This time, active admin understands admin? from the class AdminUser which was not the case yesterday. The beautiful thing is that I did not change any line of code, except commenting `# user ||= User.new` to get the expected results.

Comment: Could you t show what fields has `User` model?

Comment: And the DB fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you have two separate models - one for regular users (`users` table) and another one for admin (`admin_users` table). You can add `admin?` method to both of them - for users returning false and for admin - true.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def admin?
    false
  end
end

class AdminUser < ApplicationRecord
  # ...
  def admin?
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: I have tried user.admin? and the other possibilities to check with your solution. A good thing is I have no more 'undefined method' alerts but I get redirected to the home page. A puts in the if condition to detect admin user doesn't show any return in the console.

Comment: Could you post the code that causes redirects? Plus - do you use two models for admin and for users? Is is possible that `current_user` is an instance of `AdminUser`?

Comment: I've just added the redirection above. As for your question, I don't know. I realize that the tutorials don't mention adding the definition of admin in the model(s)!

Comment: So you probably need to add a new field to `User` model (e.g. `is_admin`), set it to true for admins and the check it in an `admin?` method.